# Path of Config file in HMVC Codeigniter (HMVC + Tank Auth)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, hmvc

I'm experiencing a problem with the paths of a config file for a module called 'auth' (which contains the tank_auth authentication library).

Every function in the 'auth' module loads the 'tank_auth.php' library which loads the tank_auth config file in `application/modules/auth/config/tank_auth.php`:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();

    $this->ci->load->config('tank_auth', TRUE); //<--- HERE IT IS!!

    $this->ci->load->library('session');
    $this->ci->load->database();
    $this->ci->load->model('tank_auth/users');

    // Try to autologin
    $this->autologin();
}
```

In another module, I insert the following call to a function in a view within the 'auth' module:

```
<?php modules::run('auth/cp');  ?>
```

This gets me the error

```
An Error Was Encountered
The configuration file tank_auth.php does not exist.
```

I solve this by changing within the __construct function in Tank_auth.php, the path from 'tank_auth' to 'auth/tank_auth'.

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->ci =& get_instance();

    $this->ci->load->config('auth/tank_auth', TRUE); // <--- ADDED module name

    $this->ci->load->library('session');
    $this->ci->load->database();
    $this->ci->load->model('tank_auth/users');

    // Try to autologin
    $this->autologin();
}
```

**My question is why doesnt the auth function cp that is being called from another module sees the config file within the 'auth' module?** Shouldnt I be able to just use `config('tank_auth', TRUE)` without adding in the name of the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats the way HMVC module is designed.

```
$this->ci->load->config('tank_auth', TRUE);
```

This will only search in the default config folder. See the "Features" section of the [official CI HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) page where it is mentioned in the context of controllers.